# Pimcore password datatype in class

Tags: passwords, pimcore

I am trying to use the Pimcore password datatype. It is working fine and the password is stored as encrypted data.

Now I need to check the correct username and password. I could not match the encrypted password. I want to get the username and password using an API request. If the username and the password is correct then return value.

Answer (score 0):

The password is hashed before it is stored to the database. Have a look at the password class within this path:

> pimcore/models/DataObject/ClassDefinition/Data/Password.php

If you want to compare the hashed password within the database then use the functions of the password datatype. The password to compare also has to be hashed.

Have a closer look on the functions `calculateHash()` and `verifyPassword()` within the class. You should be able to compare passwords by using those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
$user = User::GetByEmail($email, ['limit' => 1, 'unpublished' => false]);
$classDefinition = ClassDefinition::getById(User::classId());
/** @var \Pimcore\Model\DataObject\ClassDefinition\Data\Password $passwordFieldDefinition */
$passwordFieldDefinition = $classDefinition->getFieldDefinition('password');
$verified = $passwordFieldDefinition->verifyPassword($password, $user, false);
```